# Determinating filename and extention of downloaded (binarydata) file

Tags: java, apache, http, download

Hi guys I'm using the org.apache.http library to download a file from the web. The file is added to the webpage as an Entry (.getEntry() on the HttpResponce object) but the filename doesn't seem to be specified in the header of the webpage or in the url. The content type is application/octet-stream. The thing is that when I do the same action in a browser they both get a filename and extention. So I guess it is stored in the meta-data of the binary file but I've got no idea how to analise that. Any hints on this would be helpful.

I obtain the following headers:

```
x-amz-id-2 : dZjzVbXsHqs+dUXmJ34Nahd1wNFSaZcH0RXC54kmCEvZvj8vNaxtVViDTZB+4kV8
x-amz-request-id : 81D2B0A0469A1902
Date : Sat, 31 Jan 2015 16:18:36 GMT
Last-Modified : Sat, 17 Jan 2015 17:17:52 GMT
ETag : "3a37a8e78c37b3cb575d65539db6326c"
Accept-Ranges : bytes
Content-Type : application/octet-stream
Content-Length : 23905396
Server : AmazonS3
```

Comment: Can you post the exact HTTP headers what you get when you try and download the file? Is it an HTML5 web page?

Comment: What file name does the browser assign?

Comment: I've added the headers.

Comment: The browser assigns application.apk

Comment: @DaanLuttik thanks. And the link, does that have a `download=` attribute?

Comment: In your browser, open the network console, check if you are sending the same request headers and if you are receiving the same response headers.

Comment: Good call Sotirios I'll check that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Seemingly) The reason that chrome can find the name is because .apk is based on the zip format. And zip files contain some [header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) they can identify it as zip with a so called [Magic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)).

Comment: The feature you're referring to is called content sniffing. But this answer is incorrect. First, because apk files are indistinguishable from zip/jar archives. Second, because Chrome does not check for APK signatures. You should take a look at the response headers, and/or check whether the link looks like `<a download="file.apk" href="path/to/data">Link</a>`.

Comment: As said the headers (as far as i can tell) dont specify a name, neither does the url

Comment: Do you have a link to the resource that is served as "application.apk"? And how about my question about `<a download=... href=...>`?

Answer (score 0):

From the [HTTP Specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html)

[**Content-Type**](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.17)

> The Content-Type entity-header field indicates the media type of the
>   entity-body sent to the recipient or, in the case of the HEAD method,
>   the media type that would have been sent had the request been a GET.

[**Content-Disposition**](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec19.html#sec19.5.1)

> The Content-Disposition response-header field has been proposed as a
>   means for the origin server to suggest a default filename if the user
>   requests that the content is saved to a file.

So you can use the `Content-Disposition` header to identify a default file name.

If the server does not respond with a `Content-Disposition` header, it's up to you to identify the resource. Call it whatever you want. Probe the content to find out what it is. This is a non trivial task and that's why servers are expected to send that information.

Comment: OP has posted the headers, no `Content-Disposition`. And `application/octet-stream` doesn't give us much either.

Comment: I've added the headers so you can look